# BigCommerce style editor not working after compiling LESS CSS files

Tags: css, compilation, less, bigcommerce

I am adapting the Blueprint theme into a custom template for BigCommerce.  I compiled the theme.less file with Crunch. The style editor loads correctly and displays all of my changes correctly. However, it does not process any changes made from within style editor; nor does it allow style editor to be published.  It just "hangs."

I am uploading the four .less files:

```
style-editor-variables.less

internal-variables.less

init.less

theme.less
```

as well as the `theme.css` file, and the `style.css` file via webdav in Dreamweaver CC 2014. I have uploaded via Cyberduck, but have the same issue.

I have tried uploading the same six files without compiling them first, and most (but not all) of my changes are reflected in style editor, and style editor successfully reflects and saves changes made from within itself.

Are there any other files I need to upload (or not upload), or is there any special code I need to add in order to enable style editor to work?

Thanks for any input, advice, or guidance!